# XFCE suspend system command

Tags: command-line, suspend, xfce

When I click on the exit icon there is a suspend option.  When I click this the computer suspends, which works really well.  I want to create a custom key mapping on the suspend command `XK86Sleep` (ThinkPad sleep button) which I can create using the keyboard settings.

I have seen `pm-suspend` from numerous sources, but this requires root and so does not work.  What command does XFCE use when pressing the Suspend option through the UI as described above?

XFCE 4.8, Ubuntu 12.04, ThinkPad T60

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using this for the command

```
xfce4-session-logout -s
```

man xfce4-session-logout

> The  xfce4-session-logout command allows you to programmatically
>   logout
>          from your Xfce session. It requests the session manager to display  the
>          logout  confirmation  screen,  or,  if  given  one  of the command-line
>          options below, causes the session manager to take the requested  action
>          immediately.
>
> --suspend
>                 Suspend without displaying the logout dialog

Answer (score 6):

```
systemctl suspend
```

Also works for me.  As a bonus it works across xfce4 and cinnamon desktops.